# MySQL Best Practice for adding columns

Tags: mysql

So I started working for a company where they had 3 to 5 different tables that were often queried in either a complex join or through a double, triple query (I'm probably the 4th person to start working here, it's very messy).

Anyhow, I created a table that when querying the other 3 or 5 tables at the same time inserts that data into my table along with whatever information normally got inserted there. It has drastically sped up the page speeds for many applications and I'm wondering if I made a mistake here.

I'm hoping that in the future to remove inserting into those other tables and simply inserting all that information into the table that I've started and to switch the applications to that one table. It's just a lot faster.

Could someone tell me why it's much faster to group all the information into one massive table and if there is any downside to doing it this way?

Comment: It looks like you are de-normalizing your tabels, which might be a good thing, but it sounds like you have no real experience in this. You might want to check the slow queries, and see if they are using indexes. Read up on the `explain` command, and the usage of indexes. Don't go around and put everything in one table without proper knowledge, would be my advice.

Comment: Okay, so now I know the term for what I'm doing (thank you!) and I do not actually have much experience with MySQL tables. There are ways for each table to find each other but some are in MyISAM and others in a diff format. I think only 2 of them are linked via foreign keys. It's pretty messy.. I will check out the explain command though. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the joins are slow, it may be because the tables did not have `FOREIGN KEY` relationships and indexes properly defined. If the tables had been properly normalized before, it is probably *not* a good idea to denormalize them into a single table **unless they were not performant *with* proper indexing**.  `FOREIGN KEY` constraints require indexing on both the PK table and the related FK column, so simply defining those constraints if they don't already exist may go a long way toward improving performance.

The first course of action is to make sure the table relationships are defined correctly and the tables are indexed, before you begin denormalizing it.

There is a concept called [*materialized views*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Materialized_view), which serve as a sort of cache for views or queries whose result sets are deterministic, by storing the results of a view's query into a temporary table.  MySQL does not support materialized views directly, but you can implement them by occasionally selecting all rows from a multi-table query and storing the output into a table.  When the data in that table is stale, you overwrite it with a new rowset. For simple `SELECT` queries which are used to display data **that doesn't change often**, you may be able to speed up your pageloads using this method. It is not advisable to use it for data which is constantly changing though.

A good use for materialized views might be constructing rows to populate your site's dropdown lists or to store the result of complicated reports which are only run once a week.   A bad use for them would be to store customer order information, which requires timely access.

Comment: This is a bunch of good information. They do not have good foreign key relationships, but I can't go in and change millions of rows to get them to work together. (At least with my minimal knowledge.)

If there were proper foreign key relationships, would the speed be comparable with what I'm doing? Also what is PK/FK? (I assume FK is foreign key column.)

I am indeed using the de-normalized table for such a purpose as materialized views. The pages querying the de-normalized table never change (both page and table data).

Comment: @victoroux PK = primary key, FK = foreign key.  If the child table has a nullable column that references a key in the parent table, as long as there isn't spurious data in that column which doesnt exist in the parent table, you can try to create a FK constraint on it. If there are properly indexes and constraints defined, it will almost certainly be a lot faster -- can't say though whether it would match the performance of your single table.

Comment: Okay, I'll work on that. Thank you! Gave you the up and accept

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the table structures, etc it would be guesswork.  But it sounds like possibly the database was over-normalized.

It is hard to say exactly what the issue is without seeing it. But you might want to look at adding indexes, and foreign keys to the tables.

If you are adding a table with all of the data in it, you might be denormalizing the database.

Answer (score 0):

There are some cases where de-normalizing your tables has its advantages, but I would be more interested in finding out if the problem really lies with the table schema or with how the queries are being written.  You need to know if the queries utilize indexes (or whether indexes need to be added to the table), whether the original query writer did things like using subselects when they could have been using joins to make a query more efficient, etc.

I would not just denormalize because it makes things faster unless there is a good reason for it.

Answer (score 0):

Having a separate copy of the data in your newly defined table is a valid performance enchancing practice, but on the other hand it might become a total mess when it comes to keeping the data in your table and the other ones same. You are essentially having two truths, without good idea how to invalidate this "cache" when it comes to updates/deletes.

Read more about "normalization" and read more about "EXPLAIN" in MySQL - it will tell you why the other queries are slow and you might get away with few proper indexes and foreign keys instead of copying the data.